# Separate declarations of types/packages aliases in Ada

Tags: packaging, ada

I would like to declare some "user-defined compiler-constants" to keep my specification files as "constant" as possible. This is something common in C++, e.g. :

```
// misc/config.hh
namespace misc
{
  typedef std::shared_ptr<A> A_ptr; 
  namespace arch = ibmpc;
}

// misc/code.hh
#include "misc/config.hh"
namespace misc
{
  void function p(A_ptr a);
}
```

Which would be in Ada :

```
-- misc.ads
package Misc is
  use Types; ----> forbidden !

  procedure P(A : A_Access);
end Misc;

-- misc-types.ads
package Misc.Types is
  type A_Access is A'Access;
end Misc.Types;
```

Of course this does not work since `use` is a context keyword...hence my question : how is it possible to do something with the same results in Ada ?

Comment: `use Misc.Types;` isn’t forbidden because of the `use`, which is perfectly legal here; it’s because of the attempt to reference a child package (that hasn’t even been `with`ed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a reasonable mapping from your C++ original to Ada:

To start with, corresponding more-or-less, I think, to your `namespace misc`, in file `misc.ads`,

```
package Misc is
end Misc;
```

Then, corresponding to `config.hh`, in file `misc-config.ads`,

```
package Misc.Config is
   type A is (For_Example, An_Enumeration);
   type A_Access is access A;
end Misc.Config;
```

(which could, of course, also reference types in `Misc`). Then, corresponding to `code.hh`, in file `misc-code.ads`,

```
with Misc.Config;
package Misc.Code is
   use Config;
   procedure P (A : A_Access);
end Misc.Code;
```

Personally I wouldn’t `use Config;`, at any rate in specs - it can make it difficult to work out where something is defined. Note, you can say `use Config;` or `use Misc.Config;` where shown, because you’re in a child of `Misc`; in the context clause, which is also OK, you would have to `use Misc.Config;`.

Comment: This creates a circular dependency since `with Misc.Config;` also `with` Misc.

Comment: I don’t understand. The *exact* code I’ve posted compiles without any problems (OK, I should say it checks without any problems, because as it stands it’s missing `misc-code.adb`). I assure you I wouldn’t have posted if it didn’t!

Comment: @Julio, I really don’t understand your comment; what does "since with Misc.Config; also with Misc.” mean? There’s no circular dependency here.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that you wrapped the code in a child package `Code`. Ok, it could be a solution but it now involves writing `with Misc.Code` and `with Misc.Types` to use it :-/

Comment: I think all us old Ada hands are so used to the rule that a compilation unit must be a whole (package or subprogram, spec or body), and that with GNAT there is one compilation unit per file, that we don’t see there might be other possibilities - such as `#include`ing chunks of text which needn’t correspond to language entities. As a matter of interest, would you have the same problem with Java?

Comment: Yes, I think this is a limitation due to Ada's philosophy. And making the package generic does not make sense in my case. Since you are the only one having proposed a solution with separate files, I validate it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, while I see what you're trying to do you're going about it wrong.
The problem you have with the given sniplets is this: circular dependency.

Now Ada has a great way of managing circular dependency by making it non-circular (in a sense) through it's use of specs and bodies. As the two are discrete, we can have two sets of spec/body files where the body references the other's spec precisely because the specs are publicly visible.

As an example, admittedly ridiculous; let's use fountain-pens and ink-cartridges.

```
With Cartridge;
Package Pen is

  Subtype Model_Number is Positive Range 1000..3304;
  Type Fountain_pen is private;
  -- Pen procedures
private
  Type Fountain_pen is Record
 Model  : Model_Number;
     Ink    : Cartridge.Ink_Cartridge;
  end record;      
end Pen;
```

and

```
With Pen;
Package Cartridge is
  Type Ink_Cartridge is private;
  -- Ink procedures
private
  Type Ink_Cartridge is record
     Color      : Integer; -- I'm being lazy.
     This_Pen   : Pen.Fountain_pen;
  end record;
end Cartridge;
```

and

```
Package Body Pen is
  --- Pen Stuff
end Pen;

Package Body Cartridge is
  -- Ink stuff
end Cartridge;
```

(Not compiled.)
I forget how to create a component of a circularly-nested type though... Anyway, you should get the general idea there. But what you're wanting is fundamentally different than mutually dependent types; what you want is some sort of container for your constants.

I would recommend using child packages. Something like `Misc` and `Misc.Constants`; where you place your base-types into Misc, and the constants into Misc.Constants. If your types are dependent on your constants you might make a separate child package for them `Misc.Types` and use the mutual withing as shown above.

Comment: Er...no, you can't do that kind of circular withing as you have it in your example. You can have the *package bodies* do this "cross-withing", but if you do it in the specs the compiler will just balk at you for circular withing.

Comment: Did I screw that up? Dang... that's what I get for working off my faulty memory. (Though, I do remember using a `Misc`, `Misc.Types`, `Misc.Constants` layout.)

Comment: As I said above, I really need this child package to be in a separate file (since it needs to be in separate repositories).

Answer (score 1):

You could put the child package spec inside the parent package spec, like this:

```
package Misc is
   package Types is
      type A is private;
      type A_Access is access A;
      -- other stuff
   end Types;

   procedure P (A : Types.A_Access);
end Misc;
```

you can even `use Types;` after the declaration of `Misc.Types`.

Comment: Correct, I did a mistake in my first try. So now, how can I separate in another file this sub-package `Types` ? The example in my question-post does not compile : "Types" is undefined.