# Access child package declarations

Tags: packaging, ada

Is it possible to access child package declarations from a parent package ?

```
-- parent.ads
package Parent is
   procedure F(A : Child_Type);
end Parent;

-- parent-child.ads
package Parent.Child is
   type Child_Type is (A, B, C);
end Parent.Child;
```

The nested version works fine :

```
-- parent.ads
package Parent is
   package Child is
      type Child_Type is (A, B, C);
   end Child;
   use Child;

   procedure F(A : Child_Type);
end Parent;
```

And maybe there is another way to do this since I think it is not possible using child packages...

Comment: I had a go (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10515906/40851) at answering your other question .. using sibling packages rather than child packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no; the second example works because the specification of `Child` is known when `F` is declared in `Parent`. In light of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10434117/230513) on this topic, it may be that you want a clean way to separate multiple implementations of a common specification. This related [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10408459/230513) discusses two approaches: one using inheritance and the other using a library-based mechanism at compile-time.

Comment: So the only solution I have is to make my package generic with the types as template's paramaters...

Comment: I'll defer to more knowledgeable participants, but I don't think there's enough information to say that it's your _only_ solution. If inheritance is inappropriate, a child body can be supplied at compile-time. Gotta go, now.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is a `private` child package, this generally behaves in the same way as your nested example, but you cannot access it outside of its parent body.

Therefore :

```
private package Parent.Child is
   type Child_Type is (A,B,C);
end Parent.Child;
```

...

```
package Parent is
   procedure F;
end Parent;
```

...

```
with Ada.Text_Io;
with Parent.Child;
package body Parent is
   procedure F is
   begin
      for A in Parent.Child.Child_Type'Range loop
         Ada.Text_Io.Put_Line (Parent.Child.Child_Type'Image (A));
      end loop;
   end F;
end Parent;
```

Is ok to compile, but remember if you with the child in the parent spec (like you do with the parameter to `F`), you will get a circular dependency as children require their parents to exist first !

Therefore it really depends on *what* you want to be public to *both* the parent *and* the child whether this is an actual solution to your problem.

Comment: The thing is I really need to have the Child package in a separate file and what it contains must be transparent to use in the parent package. That's why I am looking for a solution with child packages : it can contain declarations and can be in a separate file; while it is not possible to use `separate` with declarations of types. So I am still having the same problem : I need to separate type declarations.

Comment: @JulioGuerra Is it necessary to have the type declarations somewhere in the parent.child heirachy ? If not, why not put the type declarations in parent_types.ads and with this file in parent.ads & parent.child.ads ?

Comment: This is not possible: "`with` can only appear in context clause", which is outside a package.

Comment: @JulioGuerra - No, I think you misread my suggestion - Parent_types.ads is a _new_ file. Therefore you can with it in both parent.ads & Parent-child.ads

Comment: I did not misread your post. You can't simply put declarations in a ads file, it must be a compilation unit.

Comment: But you can compile a spec file, in fact it will be compiled when you compile the first thing that uses it...

Comment: Try to declare types in a ads file, `with` it in another ads file to use the type it declares in a function; implement the function : you get a compilation **error**.

Comment: @JulioGuerra - See my next answer.

Answer (score 1):

Julio, Types declared in a spec file (mytypes.ads)

```
package Mytypes is

   type Fruit is (Apple, Pear, Pineapple, Banana, Poison_Apple);
   subtype Safe_Fruit is Fruit range Apple .. Banana;

end Mytypes;
```

...
Withed it in several others :

```
with Mytypes;
package Parent is

   function Permission (F : in Mytypes.Fruit) return Boolean;

end Parent;
```

...

```
package body Parent is

   function Permission (F : in Mytypes.Fruit) return Boolean is
   begin
      return F in Mytypes.Safe_Fruit;
   end Permission;

end Parent;
```

...

```
package Parent.Child is

   procedure Eat (F : in Mytypes.Fruit);

end Parent.Child;
```

...

```
with Ada.Text_Io;
package body Parent.Child is

   procedure Eat (F : in Mytypes.Fruit) is
   begin
      if Parent.Permission (F) then
         Ada.Text_Io.Put_Line ("Eating " & Mytypes.Fruit'Image (F));
      else
         Ada.Text_Io.Put_Line ("Forbidden to eat " & Mytypes.Fruit'Image (F));
      end if;
   end Eat;

end Parent.Child;
```

...

```
with Mytypes;
with Parent.Child;

procedure Main is

begin

   for I in Mytypes.Fruit'Range loop
      Parent.Child.Eat (I);
   end loop;

end Main;
```

It Compiles:

```
$ gnatmake main.adb
gcc-4.4 -c parent-child.adb
gnatbind -x main.ali
gnatlink main.ali
```

It Runs :

```
$ ./main
Eating APPLE
Eating PEAR
Eating PINEAPPLE
Eating BANANA
Forbidden to eat POISON_APPLE
```

Is this what you tried ?

Comment: You did not have to write a complete example :) So you put the type in a package, which is a compilation unit. Yes, it works, but there is a semantic/logic problem to me : these type belongs to the Parent package and the logic would be to have them in this package, which is so far not possible (with separation) :(